# Which pin is the one for power going to the motor in a L293D?

Tags: h-bridge

I have a L293D and I am unsure on how to connect both the power supplies for the motor and the logic of the device. I am aware that the grounds of both supplies must be connected together. But unsure on which of the power pins to use. On the pin layout there is a \$V_{SS}\$ which is pin 16 and a \$V_{S}\$ which is pin 8. So which one do I use? Here is the pin layout of the device i'm using:
[image: L293D Pin layout]

Here is the complete [datasheet](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/SGSThomsonMicroelectronics/mXyzuxsr.pdf) for the device.

Comment: But we can give 5-36 volt from pin 8 in this picture
http://320volt.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/l293d-motor-surucu-entegresi.png

Comment: You don't seem to have read the data sheet either! Pin 8 is Vss.

Comment: You need to specify the package that you are using. There are two variants with different pin assignments.

Answer (score 2):

Pin 9 of the L293D in the N or NE package is an enable pin for drivers 3 and 4 and is a logic input. Connecting it to anything over 6V is liable to damage the device.

Answer (score -3):

You connect pin 8 to 12 V or 9 V supply and connect pin 16 to 5 V.

Comment: Which package are you talking about? And how did you come up with this information?